# How to make vertical bar | work in grep?

Tags: grep

Here's an example of a grep command line I've tried:

```
grep '(565172|565173|565175)' /var/log/cups/error_log
```

It doesn't produce any output, even though all 3 values are in the file multiple times.

I tried escaping the bars, and that improved things somewhat - the middle value was detected but not the first or last.

```
grep '(565172\|565173\|565175)' /var/log/cups/error_log
```

I also tried double escapes and went back to getting no results.

```
grep '(565172\\|565173\\|565175)' /var/log/cups/error_log
```

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The syntax you are trying to use belongs to extended regular expressions, so the answer is very simple, either use `egrep` or include the `-E` flag.

Answer (score 17):

What you are running into is the difference between basic and extended regular expressions.  From grep's manual page:

> In basic regular expressions the meta-characters ?, +, {, |, (, and
>   ) lose their special meaning; instead
>   use the backslashed versions \?, +,
>   {, \|, (, and
>          ).

Thus, you can do one of the following:

```
 grep '\(565172\|565173\|565175\)' /var/log/cups/error_log
```

or

```
grep -E '(565172|565173|565175)' /var/log/cups/error_log
```

The -E flag turns on "Extended" regular expressions.  GNU grep also supports perl-compatible regular expressions.

Comment: Got distracted when writing my answer. Seems that Adam has beaten me to the punch.

Comment: But you added to the explanation - the reason I couldn't make it work is that I was escaping only the bar and not the parens.

Comment: I didn't know that you can escape these special characters once more to get the same result, so +1 for you!

Comment: The above is the most civilized set of exchanges I have ever seen in SO/SE.